# File 'root/lib/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF' uses reserved file or directory name 'lib'

Tags: android, gradle, android-app-bundle

I tried to apply for app bundle but I failed.
I can build `apk` with spilit option but I couldn't make `aab`.

I put the following gradle option.

```
    bundle {
        abi {
            enableSplit = true
        }
    }
```

The error message in the console is below.

```
    File 'root/lib/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF' uses reserved file or directory name 'lib'.
```

The file structure that was built is like below.
[image]

I heard I have to add the below library, but I didn't.
Actually, there is no difference either I add the play core library or not.

```
    implementation "com.google.android.play:core:$play_version"
```

I wanna change some options to avoid alias problem but I don't have any idea about that.

Anyone who can handle this problem simply?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you don't have a directory called "lib/" in your project, since this directory name is reserved in the APK format for storing native libraries.

If not in your project, one your library dependencies must have it and is being copied into the APK.

The reason it works for APKs but not AABs is that the AAB format is more strict and will prevent you from embedding unnecessary files in your app.

Comment: Thank you for replying. The problem was another task was using `/lib` for copying native so files.